# ASP.net C# How can I make it so only one field in database updates in update page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm fairly new to coding in general so sorry if some of my jargon is wrong.

I have a database that stores the image name of files in for my homepage, so that an admin can upload new images to replace the previous images in database so that it posts the new uploaded images to the homepage.

The problem I am currently having is that when I just want to update one of the images, it uploads that image but the other images are replaced with null values, I only want the field I uploaded the image to, to be updated.

Here is my code behind, I have a fair idea what I'm doing wrong, however, I don't really now how to remedy my problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Configuration;

public partial class admin_updatehomepage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void displayedit_ItemUpdated(object sender, ListViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        info.Text = "Item Updated";

        FileUpload fileupdate1 = displayedit.EditItem.FindControl("imageupdate1") as FileUpload;
        FileUpload fileupdate2 = displayedit.EditItem.FindControl("imageupdate2") as FileUpload;
        FileUpload fileupdate3 = displayedit.EditItem.FindControl("imageupdate3") as FileUpload;
        FileUpload fileupdate4 = displayedit.EditItem.FindControl("imageupdate4") as FileUpload;
        FileUpload fileupdate5 = displayedit.EditItem.FindControl("imageupdate5") as FileUpload;
        FileUpload fileupdate6 = displayedit.EditItem.FindControl("imageupdate6") as FileUpload;
        FileUpload fileupdate7 = displayedit.EditItem.FindControl("imageupdate7") as FileUpload;
        FileUpload fileupdate8 = displayedit.EditItem.FindControl("imageupdate8") as FileUpload;
        FileUpload fileupdate9 = displayedit.EditItem.FindControl("imageupdate9") as FileUpload;

        Label recordid = displayedit.EditItem.FindControl("idlabel1") as Label;
        Int32 id = Convert.ToInt32(recordid.Text);

        if (fileupdate1.HasFile)
        {
            String fupload = fileupdate1.FileName;

            Random r = new Random();
            int rInt = r.Next(0, 10000);

            String imgpath = "../images/" + rInt + fupload;

            fileupdate1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(imgpath));

            String newimage = rInt + fupload;

            string newsconnection = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["newsconnection"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(newsconnection);

            //myConnection.ConnectionString is now set to connectionString.
            myConnection.Open();

            String query = "UPDATE homepage SET fballimg ='" + newimage + "' WHERE id='" + id + "'";

            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);

            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            myConnection.Close();
        }
        if (fileupdate2.HasFile)
        {
            String fupload = fileupdate2.FileName;

            Random r = new Random();
            int rInt = r.Next(0, 10000);

            String imgpath = "../images/" + rInt + fupload;

            fileupdate2.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(imgpath));

            String newimage = rInt + fupload;

            string newsconnection = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["newsconnection"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(newsconnection);

            //myConnection.ConnectionString is now set to connectionString.
            myConnection.Open();

            String query = "UPDATE homepage SET rugbyimg ='" + newimage + "' WHERE id='" + id + "'";

            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);

            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            myConnection.Close();
        }
        if (fileupdate3.HasFile)
        {
            String fupload = fileupdate3.FileName;

            Random r = new Random();
            int rInt = r.Next(0, 10000);

            String imgpath = "../images/" + rInt + fupload;

            fileupdate3.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(imgpath));

            String newimage = rInt + fupload;

            string newsconnection = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["newsconnection"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(newsconnection);

            //myConnection.ConnectionString is now set to connectionString.
            myConnection.Open();

            String query = "UPDATE homepage SET bballimg ='" + newimage + "' WHERE id='" + id + "'";

            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);

            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            myConnection.Close();
        }
    }
    protected void displayedit_ItemEditing(object sender, ListViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        info.Text = "<b>*Recommend images are 490px x 190px(or of similar ratio) to avoid image distortion</b>";
    }
    protected void displayedit_ItemCanceling(object sender, ListViewCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        info.Text = "Not Updating";
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume you are storing image paths in those fields. Hence in your update query you have to set the other two fields to `''` (_blank_ or _empty string_).

Comment: @deostroll Do you mean like this? `String query = "UPDATE homepage SET fballimg ='" + newimage + "', rugbyimg='', bballimg='' WHERE id='" + id + "'";`

Comment: Yep. Is it only three images in that table?

Comment: I have 9, I assume I add those to the update query in the same manner?

Comment: go for a parameterized update query - with nine parameters. By default set all 9 to `string.Empty`, set only the ones which have images with corresponding paths...

Answer (score 0):

try this...

Store the names of each image in the different hiddenfield....

Now while updating check the :

```
if (fileupdateId.HasFile)
{
    //then new file name
}
else
{
   //else hiddenfield value
}
```

do let me know if any query is there..